# Is a knife-edge cutover still possible with BES 5.01?

Tags: bes

We have a Primary BES with a local SQL Express DB instance running BES 5.01. We built a backup BES by using the same SRP key (after stopping services on primary) and backed up and restored the BESMgmt from Server1 to Server2. We were finally able to get the BAS site working on Server2, but a few services are not starting on the it, such as the Mail Store, Dispatcher, and Router.

I have been able to do this in the past with pre 5.0 versions of BES, but it seems like with the introduction of HA, it may not be supported anymore. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Been there.  Simply backing up and restoring the database is not sufficient.  Among many other things, one must run the "createdb.exe" tool prior to restoring.

All of the necessary details can be found here:

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/viewContent.do?externalId=KB03112

Comment: The destination server I restored to already had a blank copy of the BESMgmt DB, negating the need to run createdb.exe it seems, as shown in the article. I overwrote the blank DB with the restored one but that's where some of the services fail to start.

Comment: In my own experience, it doesn't work unless the prescribed steps are followed in detail.  There are too many "gotchas" to make it work solely by the power of experience and intuition: unnecessary complexity is a hallmark of BBES.  However, if you really want to work from where you currently stand instead of starting over, your Windows event logs may give a few clues as to why the services aren't starting.  Good luck!